# Why do people censor serverfault questions that are interesting and valuable due to personal bias?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, allowed-topics

My comment was closed here at [Robot Datacenter Automation, can it be done?](https://serverfault.com/questions/155196/robot-datacenter-automation-can-it-be-done) because a number of individuals felt it too vague. Well, all of the interesting and useful discussions are. Furthermore, someone actually could build a mechanical automation of a datacenter, so there is no qualification that this is just rhetoric or ambiguous. Clearly people were interested in the topic because it received much response in the short amount of time the thread was left open.

Be more careful when you censor someones comment. I will be taking my discussion posts elsewhere.

Comment: ServerFault (and the other associated sites) are not discussions boards. So yes, if you want to have true discussions, feel free to take them elsewhere. On the other hand, if you want to ask well-articulated questions, then this is perhaps the best place on the interwebs to do so.

Comment: Questions are closed by people who have been using the site long enough to know what types of questions fit well in the intended Q&A format.  Perhaps this is a bit biased, but it is biased towards keeping the site from becoming Yahoo answers.

Answer (score 12):

One of the best things about Serverfault, Stackoverflow, and Superuser is how clean, organized, and consistent their information is. It's only due to the self-organizing, self-policing nature of these sites that they are able to maintain such a high Signal-to-noise ratio.

In your case, you posted a somewhat theoretical, vague question. As such myself and several others flagged it so that it would be closed. If you can think of a better, more concise way of asking that same question, by all means do so!

Comment: I don't feel the need to. Perhaps this is not the right forum for thought that involves innovative thought, but is more of a support forum, is that accurate?

Comment: @msacks We're not a forum. We're a question-and-answer site. People ask questions, they get solid answers. These can involve innovative  and well-articulated thoughts, but those thoughts do not require discussion. And judging by what everyone else is saying about your question, it was leaning more towards the open-ended discussion route rather than a question with an answer.

Comment: It's a peer-to-peer Q&A forum. If you spend some time here, you'll certainly see that there is a great deal of innovative thought that goes on. In this case, though, that innovative thought is directed at solving concrete, real-world problems, not so much on theoretical questions.

Answer (score 5):

Well the fact that you use the following phrase:

> What if there was a fully automated system of robots

shows that this is not a specific question with a correct answer.  Tuns, it isn't a fit question for Server Fault.

Answer (score 2):

I would not have been closed it but from my point of view it's true that the question is a bit ambiguous and has part of an answer inside it. I would have ask it like this:
"Maintenace in a Datacenter is time consuming (racking hardware, changing drives, ...), how do you do to reduce time spend on this? Is there any automation solution?"
this question let people share their experience in managing a datacenter instead of asking why datacenter robot doesn't exist

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question was in regard to mechanical automation, which is a valid question.

Comment: Yes, it's most certainly a valid question. As others have mentioned, those type of questions are not what these sites are about.